# Timeout when resolving zeroconf service registered on Android device

Tags: android, bonjour, zeroconf

I'm having a problem resolving a zeroconf service started on my Android device (Captivate, Android 2.2).  Using avahi-discover on Ubuntu I can see the registered service just fine, but trying to resolve it gives an error of "Error: org.freedesktop.Avahi.TimeoutError: Timeout reached".  This is causing a problem for my app (ad-hoc message sharing for relief work/activism) which needs the service to be resolved in order receive its IP or link-local name along with its port.

Note: My Android device is successfully able to resolve zeroconf services registered on other devices, such as my Ubuntu machines, thus this is not the same problem as [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474143/how-can-i-discover-zeroconf-bonjour-services-on-android-im-having-trouble-wit).

On the android side the code couldn't be simpler:

```
serviceInfo = ServiceInfo.create("_fluidnexus._tcp.local.", "Fluid Nexus", 17894, "Fluid Nexus Zeroconf server for android");
jmdns.registerService(serviceInfo);
```

This code is part of a thread that is started by an Android service that is in turn started by my main Activity.  All jmdns calls are made from within the same thread.  A separate thread accepts connections on that port and does not call any jmdns code.

This would appear to not be a lock issue as I'm able to discover/resolve other zeroconf services without issue, but to be honest I'm not entirely clear on the lifecycle use of the lock when registering my own service on Android.

If you want to see the code in context it's available on [github](https://github.com/zeitkunst/FluidNexusAndroid/blob/experimental/src/net/fluidnexus/FluidNexus/services/ZeroconfServiceThread.java).

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Any luck on this? I have the same problem. Service resolution works on  my Kindle Fire but not on my Galaxy Nexus or Google TV. Beats me.

Comment: I unfortunately haven't found a solution, no.  Since this was from a side project that I'm not actively working on now, I haven't been able to look into in more depth.  I'm hoping someone finds this and posts a solution to help the both of us!