# How to make networked software aware of itself?

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, bonjour, native-activity

I have an Android and iOS app that I would like to be accessible through PC software.  Currently, the mobile application will display an IP address and the PC user must manually type this number in to create a connection.

I know there is some sort of broadcasting standards, but I'm having trouble figuring out what method make sense in my case.

A solution that works for both Android (native activity, version >= 2.3.3) and iOS would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour by Apple might be what you're looking for. It allows your application to broadcast your service over the local network so that the PC will automatically discover it. You can find more information [here](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/).

Comment: Is it worth using over zeroconf?  Is it open?

Comment: I don't have experience with zeroconf, however using Bonjour might simplify getting things running on iOS (although it could make things more complicated with Android). According to Apple's website, the source is available under the apache license.

Comment: I was definitely hoping for something that was a bit more platform-independent.

Comment: JellyBean has a Network Service Discovery Manager. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager.html They mention bonjour on developer.android.com it seems like the way to go.

Comment: I need 2.3.3 or higher to be fully supported.

Comment: From what I can tell, Bonjour is Apple's implementation of zeroconf so it should play nicely across platforms. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474143/how-can-i-discover-zeroconf-bonjour-services-on-android-im-having-trouble-wi). It mentions using jmDNS for Android 2.0.1.

Comment: This might work if I JNI it all.  I forgot to mention, I'm using C++ native activity.  Changed my tagged and clarified.