# Bonjour DNSServiceRegister on Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, mdns, dns-sd

I am using the Android NDK, with dns_sd.h code that works fine on other platforms: https://github.com/HBPVIS/Servus/blob/master/servus/dnssd/servus.h

On Android, the library is calling `DNSServiceRegister`, there is no error return code, but a DNS-SD inspection tool (avahi-discover) shows me that there is nothing announced in the network.

I enabled the following permissions:

```
ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE
ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
```

I link against Android's [mDNSResponder implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/mdnsresponder/), and link against the shim library as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9946650/1495627).

Comment: You can call [NSD API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/package-summary.html) to do this if your Android version >= Jelly Bean. It's easy to use though it's buggy.

Comment: I'd rather have no Java code at all in my app (I currently don't).

Comment: Same taste with me, just too tired:)

Comment: I have the same issue...some recommend to acquire a multicast lock (wifi.createMulticastLock) but that didn't work either.